# ArcGIS: Geometric Network, Service Areas? OD Cost Matrix?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, geometric-network

With ArcGIS Desktop is it possible to run Service areas and OD cost matrix analysis on Geometric networks (ex:gas network)usi ng the network analyst extension?

Comment: network analyst extension only

Comment: So then I understand that the network analysis like Service Areas and OD cost matrix can be performed on geometric networks? I have just used them on road networks, that's why I am asking.

Comment: No. Geometric networks and network datasets are different network types. You cannot run Network Analyst solvers on a Geometric network